# covariance matrix in bivariate distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, covariance

I struggle to understand how exactly you get the covariance matrix in a bivariate normal distribution. The reason is probably that I have no idea how to obtain it at all. In the exercise I have I already have $\sigma_{11}^2$ and $\sigma_{22}^2$ as well as $\rho_{12}$. I also have the two $\mu$ values. But with the formulas I find around the internet I'm not able to figure out how to calculate the covariance matrix for that distribution. How do I start here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). You will get:

$$
\Sigma = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{1}^2 & \rho_{12} \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2} \\
\rho_{12} \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2} & \sigma_{2}^2 \end{array} \right)
$$